# Is it possible to write a macro that runs bit manipulation on its input and is used as a pattern in a match?

Tags: rust, macros

I am writing a terminal text editor in Rust, and have been following along with a [guide written for C](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/03.rawInputAndOutput.html). The recommendation in the guide is to use a macro in order to simplify testing of whether a key and ctrl have been pressed at the same time:

```c
#define CTRL_KEY(k) ((k) & 0x1f)
```

I haven't written many macros in Rust, and haven't had much success recreating this macro. Here is the macro that I've written:

```rust
macro_rules! ctrl_key {
    ( $x: expr ) => {{
        $x & 0b00011111
    }};
}
```

I'm using it as a match condition:

```rust
match value {
    ctrl_key!(b'q') => break,
    _ => {}
}
```

The compiler tells me `this macro call doesn't expand to a pattern in this macro invocation`. Is it possible to write a macro that accomplishes what I'm trying to accomplish (specifically in the context of the match condition)?  Could I use a macro to convert to bytes, so that instead of `b'q'`, I would just need to write `'q'`?

Comment: You can make your code work today [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d349d6dabd28a58c0f3fc65696ebcd78). Anything more complicated requires the linked duplicate.

Comment: I would say that a macro isn't really needed here (or even in the C, seemingly). [A plain function would work fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a8c4cc39475551fc36b8dbb48c2f013b).